# Elimination method algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

[image]
I am having some trouble understanding this solution to a question which required the elimination method. It comes from page 266 of Head First Algebra.

On the right hand side why does the + 0.4p become -0.6p on the next line?

I understand everything else, even the cancelling out parts I think.

Thank you.

Comment: We actually appreciate not-posting pictures.  Instead, type your question and work right into the post.  This way it's permanent.  See the mathjax tutorial:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Could you or someone edit my post and do it? Sorry but I am on my phone and it's very difficult to type.

Comment: Probably it was just p subtrated. It is hard to help without knowing what is going on.

Comment: I would suggest that you talk to the person who wrote those notes.  Having graded a lot of assignments that look very much like what is written there, I suspect that I could probably parse it if I tried, but they are written in a manner which indicates that there was an oral description of the process as the steps were written out.  I doubt that there is very much that we could do here which couldn't be done better by the original author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how the entire first equation is multiplied by $-1$, turning the system into
$$\begin{align}
-c-p&=-5 \\
c+0.4p&=2.6
\end{align}$$
Those two equations are then added together to produce
$$\require{cancel}\cancel{c-c}-p+0.4p=-2.4$$
which simplifies to
$$p(-1+0.4)=-2.4 \implies -0.6p=-2.4$$

Comment: I really appreciate your post but because of it being wrote on a line I find it difficult to follow sorry.

Comment: What about it was difficult to follow? Are the equations not showing up nicely for you? I could explain it only using words, if that would be easier.

Comment: I see things on a single line and I'm not used to that format. I understand it, like the simplification etc... but still cannot see where that number came from.

Comment: I'm still a little confused, sorry. Is it my answer that's hard to follow or some part of the way the question is written in your book that's hard to follow?

Comment: Your answer sorry. Too much is on one line. I am still confused where the -0.6p came from. I understand everything else: multiplying by -1, cancelling out the equation etc... I just do not see where that came from. I cannot slot it all together in my head.

Comment: No worries; I can explain it in words here in the comments. Basically, the $0.4p$ turns into $-0.6p$ because it's being added to the $-p$ in the equation above it. That equation with the $-p$, in turn, comes from multiplying the first equation in the system by $-1$.

Comment: To clarify after you simplify the equation I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Your written comment helped. How does:  -p * 0.4p = turn into -0.6p. ?!

Comment: The two expressions, $-p$ and $0.4p$, aren't being multiplied together; they're being added. It's the same idea as how you can add $x$ and $2x$ together to produce $3x$. You just add the coefficients together, so in the example I just gave with the $x$'s, $1+2=3$, and in the case of the original problem, with the $p$'s, $-1+0.4=-0.6$. Also, would you like to move this conversation to chat? Long discussions in the comments are generally discouraged, and chat is better for that sort of thing.

Comment: I understand now and I feel stupid for overthinking this, thank you!!!

Comment: You're more than welcome. Feeling stupid is a good thing, though; it means you learned something!

Comment: Sorry to message again, I understand the answer, but I had a question. The way the answer is displayed it very different to the book, or my experience in both UK and Spanish schools. I assume the ===> is an arrow, but why not just structure it the same way the book does? Maybe what you do is more advanced, but surely "my" way is easier to read?

Comment: That's okay! All the arrow means is that what's before it implies what's after it. In other words, $p(-1+0.4)=-2.4$, *which means that* $-0.6p=-2.4$. All you have to do once you reach $-0.6p=-2.4$ is solve for $p$, plug it back in, and solve for $c$, and you're done.